# Make two Sass mixins aware of each other: the output of one mixin should be different depending on how the other mixin was applied

Tags: css, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I'm building a reusable, customizable component. The component has several configuration options, each option has several values to choose from.

Consider these two options for example:

- `content-position`: `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, `center`,
- `content-padding`: `small`, `medium`, `large`.

The tricky part is that the padding must be different depending on the position. E. g. when content position is `left`, then the left padding must be enlarged and the right padding must be reduced.

It's pretty trivial to achieve with HTML classes:

```html
<MyComponent class="--content-position-left --content-padding-small"/>
```

```
.MyComponent__Content {
  .MyComponent.--content-padding-small & {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .MyComponent.--content-padding-small.--content-position-left & {
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-right: 25px
  }

  .MyComponent.--content-padding-medium & {
    padding: 100px;
  }
  .MyComponent.--content-padding-medium.--content-position-left & {
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly when you are OK with applying configuration via HTML.

But I want to provide a way of configuring this component with pure Sass, without applying HTML classes.

It should be possible to do something like this:

```
.Page__Products {
  .MyComponent {
    @include my-component--content-position("left");
    @include my-component--content-padding("small");
  }
}
```

**How can I make the `my-component--content-padding` know which padding side should be larger, if any?**

I see two obvious solutions:

1. Merge two mixins into one, and make it accept two arguments, something like:

   ```
   @include my-component--content-position-and-padding("small", "left");
   ```

   I don't like this approach. It gets really messy when there are multiple options depending on each other.
   Instead of multiple single-purpose mixins, you end up with a single "god" mixin to control everything.
2. Keep mixins separate, but make each mixin accept all the information it needs:

   ```
   @include my-component--content-position("left");
   @include my-component--content-padding("small", "left");
   ```

   This is better, but I don't like the redundancy: you have to specify `"left"` twice.

**So I wonder if I could do the following, and the padding mixin would know how exactly to distort padding depending on which position has been applied by the other mixin:**

```
.Page__Products {
  .MyComponent {
    @include my-component--content-position("left");
    @include my-component--content-padding("small");
  }
}
```

This would be trivial to do with a real programming language, but Sass seems to fall short?

PS I don't want mixins to depend on the order they have been applied in and on global variables.

Comment: The only other solution I see is to create a third mixin that takes one argument (`$position`) and then call these two mixins with the right parameters using `@if` `@else` conditions. Though, it's kind of similar to your first solution.

Comment: Would a local variable in your selector to store the position be acceptable? So you don't have to specify it twice.

Comment: @Arkellys local variable in the selector? How is it different from applying an HTML class?

Comment: No, I meant using your solution 2 but instead of writing `"left"` twice you store it in a variable inside the selector and then use the variable as an argument of your mixins.

Comment: OK, I get it. Yeah, I would do that, but the goal of this question is to reduce the footprint of mixins, the amount of their responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

constants:

```
$none: none;
$left: left;
$right: right;
$mediumPadding: 100px;
$mediumPaddingLeft: 100px 50px 100px 150px;
$mediumPaddingRight: 100px 150px 100px 50px;
$smallPadding: 50px;
$smallPaddingLeft: 50px 25px 50px 75px;
$smallPaddingRight: 50px 75px 50px 25px;
```

Mixins:

```
@mixin align-padding($align, $padding)
{
    float: $align;
    padding: $padding;
}
```

SCSS:

```
.what-you-want-to-hang-it-on
{
    @include align-padding($none, $mediumpadding);
}
```

Comment: There's only one mixin in your answer. 

Comment: Yes @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus that is the beauty of it, one powerful mixin, it is up to you how you apply it. The scss example is only one of the combinations you can use.

Comment: How is it different from "Obvious solution number 1" in the original question?